# Variable number of async threads with C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I'm working on a program where I'd like to use async in a loop. In the example code I've included there's only 10 elements, so I could easily create an explicit variable for each element. However, in my main program, the number of elements in the vector can vary. Ideally, I'd like to create a vector of async threads - one for every element in the array - which are pushed back on the async vector as I loop through.Then I want to wait for them all to complete, and then use "get()" to return all of their outputs.

The code below will call async by assigning an explicit variable for each thread, but does anyone know how to dynamically call async in a vector without having to explicitly assign a variable to it? Ideally, I'd like for this program to call "std::cout" once for each time it looped through, instead of just once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <future>

std::string hi (std::string input)
{
    return "hello, this is " + input;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> test_vector( 10, "a test" );
    std::future<std::string> a;
    std::future<std::string> b;

    for ( int i = 0; i < test_vector.size ( ); i++ )
    {
        a = std::async(std::launch::async, hi, test_vector[i]);
    }

    std::cout << a.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: And what precisely is your question?

Comment: How to dynamically call async each time the loop passes instead of having to explicitly create a variable.

Comment: The code as written above has a serious flaw, every time you assign a new future to `a` you force it to block and wait for the thread associated with its old value to finish, so you're effectively running in serial. Anyway, I'm surprised the solution to a dynamic number of futures isn't completely obvious: store each new future in a dynamically-sized container, like a vector. You even said that yourself: _"I'd like to create a vector of async threads - one for every element in the array - which are pushed back on the async vector as I loop through."_ so why didn't you just do that!

Comment: Vectors were the best way I could describe it, I'd tried using this kind of thing but hadn't got any speed up and wanted to see what others suggested, although this seems to be the only way to do it and my program didn't run any faster.

Comment: Maybe the async function will call itself recursively? I don't know if that is possible, and you will have to wait the overhead of calling the first function but once you have two running, these two will call another two and it'll grow recursively. Maybe that is what you are looking for. Set a global variable with a mutex so that the threads can see how many threads where called and interrupt the recursion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An answer including `std::cout`:

```
std::vector<std::future<std::string>> a;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  a.emplace_back(std::async(hi));
}
for (auto& element : a) {
  std::cout << element.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can solve this by creating a vector of futures to match your threads vector, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <future>

std::string hi(const std::string& input)
{
    return "hello, this is " + input;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tests = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
    std::vector<std::future<std::string>> futures;

    // add the futures to the futures vector as you launch
    // your asynchronous functions
    for(auto&& t: tests)
        futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, hi, std::cref(t)));

    // collect your results
    for(auto&& f: futures)
        std::cout << f.get() << '\n';
}
```

Note the use of [std::cref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to pass by *const reference*. Use [std::ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to pass *non const references*.

Comment: Checking [`std::future::valid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/valid) is extraneous here, it will always return true.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, could be something like:

```
std::vector<std::future<std::string>> vessel;
for ( int i = 0; i < test_vector.size ( ); i++ )
{
    std::future<std::string> aux;
    aux = std::async(std::launch::async, hi);
    vessel.push_back(aux);
}
```

Sorry I cannot post as a comment, but this way, depending on the logic, and if it works, then you should be able to dynamically manipulate the vector `vessel`.

---

**Update**

better yet:

```
vessel.push_back(new std::future<std::string>);
vessel[vessel.size()-1] = std::async(std::launch::async, hi);
```

this way you don't need to explicitly declare a variable. But you will have to `delete` once you are done:

```
for(int i=0; i<(int) vessel.size(); i++)
{
    delete vessel[i];
}
```

Comment: At [CPlusPlus unique_ptr reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/), it is stated that `unique_ptr objects automatically delete the object they manage (using a deleter) as soon as they themselves are destroyed`. Thanks for pointing it out @0x499602D2. This [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/get/) ilustrates how it shoud be used.

Comment: Better not use raw pointers (exception-safety), even better: don't use pointers at all. As Galiks answer shows, it's perfectly reasonable to don't use them. Reducing indirection is a good idea (although the cost is probably negligible here).

Comment: Even ignoring the fact your "better yet" version doesn't compile (you can't assign a `std::future` to a `std::future*`) there is no reason whatsoever to dynamically allocate the futures. `vessel.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, hi)` works perfectly, is safer, and is at least as efficient because it performs fewer allocations and pointer indirections.

Comment: I will update the answer. I should have tested it. I will get the hang of helping people here. It was just recently though that I finished a OOP course at college and I'm trying to put it to good use.